# Як правильно буде українською "desktop application"?

Tags: переклад, терміни, from-english

Чи існує в українській мові сталий термін, що відповідає англійському "desktop application" (мається на увазі програмне забезпечення, що призначено для використання на персональному комп'ютері)? Чи коректно буде перекласти цей термін, як: "настільний застосунок"?

Comment: Мабуть має право на існування як скорочене від застосунок для настільного ПК

Comment: "Настільний доданок" або "персональний доданок"

Comment: mobile application = мобільний додаток, для десктопів по аналогії використовуються словосполучення: "комп'ютерна програма, комп'ютерний додаток", при чому прикметником "комп'ютерний" дозволяється нехтувати

Comment: Згоден, саме "доданок" найбільш усталена форма на мій погляд

Comment: Чи не дублікат до [«Що є більш правильним „застосунок“ чи „додаток“?»](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/61/4)?

Comment: @Sasha, "application" - більш широке поняття, desktop application - все таки застосунок для "великих комп'ютерів". Хоча з приходом планшетів та трансформерів поняття desktop стало більш розмитим.

Comment: НІ. Software applications поділяють на desktop application та mobile application.

Answer (score 36):

### Desktop

Англійський термін "desktop" у формі прикметника має декілька перекладів:

1. **Десктопний** - транслітерація з англійської. Є здебільшого сленговим, вузькопрофесійним терміном у колах програмістів, дизайнерів і системних адміністраторів, не має широкого використання ані серед звичайних користувачів, ані в офіційних перекладах для різних систем.

   > [https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=десктопні+програми](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BD%D1%96+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8)
   >
   > 39,300 результатів
   >
   > "Так, я пишу десктопні програми під Windows"
   >
   > "Десктопні програми на веб-технологіях - відео урок - Майстер-клас"
   >
   > "У яких випадках мова програмування Python є правильним вибором"
   >
   > *Висновок: дуже мало результатів пошуку в Гугл, майже всі є посиланнями на професійні ресурси.*
2. **Стільниковий** - спроба дослівного перекладу з англійської. Не має широкого використання у звичайній мові.

   > [https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=стільникові+програми](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8)
   >
   > 127,000 результатів
   >
   > "Стільникові параметри - iPhone, Довідка iPhone - iPhone Help"
   >
   > "Настройки стільникової мережі й SIM-картки - Microsoft Support"
   >
   > "Налаштування - Lifecell"
   >
   > *Висновок - небагато результатів пошуку в Гугл, майже всі результати відносяться до **стільникового звʼязку** і жодним чином не повʼязані з терміном "desktop"*
3. **Компʼютерний** - найпоширеніший за використанням термін, зрозумілий будь-якій людині, що вільно володіє українською. Майже точно збігається за значенням з терміном "desktop", на противагу з "mobile", що зазвичай перекладається як "мобільний".

   > [https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=компʼютерні+програми](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%CA%BC%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%96+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8)
   >
   > 224,000 результатів
   >
   > "Комп'ютерна програма — Вікіпедія"
   >
   > "AVIRA – безкоштовна антивірусна програма"
   >
   > "Звантажити безкоштовні програми. Бібліотека безкоштовних програм — збірка якісних програм для роботи на комп'ютері."
   >
   > *Висновок - найбільша кількість результатів, майже стовідсотковий збіг за значенням із треміном desktop*

### Application

З історії слова "application" відомо, що спочатку в англійській мові було словосполучення "application program", а вже потім його скоротили до "application".

> *Wikipedia:*
>
> An application program (app or application for short) is a computer program designed to perform a group of coordinated functions, tasks, or activities for the benefit of the user.

Дуже гарний коментар від @Mykola, наводжу його повністю:

> Проблема перекладу application в тому, що намагаються перекласти одне слово без контексту. Згадане словосполучення 'application program' треба перекладати як 'прикладна програма' (так само як applied math - прикладна математика). Нехай в англійській скоротили application program до application (потім до app). В українській не обов'язково копіювати стиль скорочення словосполучень, і вигадувати новотвори - застосунок, прикладунок... Вважаю цілком достатнім використовувати термін програма.

Для англійського "application" існує декілька варіантів перекладу:

1. **Застосунок** - зустрічається здебільшого у словниках, причому словниках походженням з 90-х років, коли не було нормальної, усталеної термінології в інформатиці і програмуванні. Особисто мені ріже слух і є не найкращим з варіантів, бо є дослівним перекладом зі слова "application", без розуміння, що це був за application і до чого його "застосовували". Скоріш за все, цей термін було вигадано людьми, що добре знали українську і, можливо, навіть англійську, але дуже погано розумілися на компʼютерах та компʼютерній термінології.
2. **Аплікація** - транслітерація з англійського "application". Ріже слух ще гірше за "застосунок". У пересічного українця викликає асоціації з нарізанням і наклеюванням кольорових папірців, але аж ніяк не з програмами.
3. **Програма** - цей переклад набагато ближчий до оригінального значення і часто використовується у неформальній мові, а також в офіційних перекладах інтерфейсів операційних систем.

   > *Цитата 1 з офіційного сайта Microsoft https://www.microsoft.com/uk-ua/windows/windows-10-apps*
   >
   > Популярні платні *програми*
   >
   > Основні *програми*
   >
   > ---
   >
   > *Цитата 2 з офіційного сайта Apple https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18738?locale=en_US&viewlocale=uk_UA*
   >
   > *Програми*, що постачаються з комп’ютером Mac
   >
   > Комп’ютер Mac постачається з численними корисними *програмами*. Деякі з цих *програм* можна запустити з панелі Dock. Щоб переглянути та запустити всі ці *програми*, натисніть іконку Launchpad.
4. **Додаток** - найчастіше використовується у контексті програм для мобільних пристроїв, але може бути використано і для "desktop application". Також усталений термін неформальної мови, реклами, зустрічається у багатьох офіційних перекладах інтерфейсів операційних систем.
   Не є калькою з англійської, а виступає як органічний термін української мови. Існує *операційна система* (Windows, OSX, Android, iOS, і т.п.), вона дає користувачу можливість працювати з графічним інтерфейсом, виконувати багато різних функцій і є повноцінним самостійним продуктом. Для операційної системи існують *додатки*, які розширюють її функціональність і дають змогу користувачу робити *додаткові* дії.
   Водночас термін *додаток* є дещо суперечливим. Існує думка, що *додаток* походить від російського *приложение*, що так само не має сенсу, як і *застосунок*. Дивись дискусію нижче.

   > *Цитата з Google Play Store https://play.google.com/store/apps?hl=uk*
   >
   > Мої *додатки*
   >
   > Нові й оновлені *додатки*
   >
   > Сімейні додатки

Тож, підсумовуюче вищесказане, найкраще перекласти "desktop application" як **компʼютерна програма**.

*P.S. Важливою якістю терміна у будь-якій мові є той факт, що цей термін є зрозумілим більшості (в ідеалі - всім) носіям цієї мови. Вузькоспеціалізовані, рафіновано-академічні, архаїчні терміни погані тим, що зрозумілі лише небагатьом людям, тому не можуть вважатись на 100% справжніми словами живої сучасної мови. Уявіть на секунду, про що подумає ваша бабуся з села (або навіть ваша дівчина з журфака, або ваш батько-будівельник), коли ви скажете їй: "а чи не встановити тобі стільниковий застосунок?" А потім порівняйте це з реакцією людини на слова "чи не встановити тобі комʼютерну програму?".*

Comment: Добра розгорнута відповідь! Добре розкрито зміст слова `Application`, але було б добре, якби Ви надали посилання (цитати) до опису слова `Desctop`. Слово `стільниковий` в мене стійко асоціюється з `стільниковий зв'язок`. `Компʼютерний - найпоширеніший за використанням термін` - більше скидається на суб'єктивну думку (принаймі без посилань).

Comment: Ще одне важливе зауваження.

Окремо розрізняють *desktop* і *laptop* як категорію пристроїв, але **не** розрізняють *desktop application* і *laptop application*, бо на них запускаються одні й ті самі операційні системи.  Натомість окремо вирізняють *mobile application*, бо там дійсно інша ОС, а також *web application*, бо запускається всередині бравзера (який може бути запущений як на *desktop*, так і на *laptop*, так і на *mobile*).

Таким чином, *desktop application* є архаїзмом і не варто перекладати його (*desktop*) взагалі.

Comment: Про "додаток" ви пишете, що це "Не є калькою з англійської, а виступає як органічний термін української мови.", але не зазначаєте, що це калька з російського "приложение" і теж зроблена без розуміння змісту, бо рос. "приложение" має кілька значень (прикладная математика, приложение к документу), в той час я додаток є прямим перекладом другого, неправильного в контексті прикладних програм, значення (в укр. кажемо додаток до документа, але не додаткова математика)

Comment: @Miroshko Для мене це лише співпадіння, що це збігається якось зі словом "приложение". Тут `додаток` - це переклад англійського слова `extension`, яке широко використовується для чогось, що встановлюється на вже готову платформу. Можна було б перекласти як `розширення`, але особисто мені `додаток` звучить краще, та й використовується на порядки частіше.

Comment: extension не є синонімом application, це два окремі класи програм (extension – розширює, application – застосовується. Browser extension не можна назвати browser application, а Powerpoint ніхто не назве extension, бо це не розширення іншого ПЗ, операційної системи тощо). Єдиний зв'язок — через російську, де вони перекладаються омонімом "Приложение". Хоча варто відмімити, що росіяни теж переважно вважають, що "приложение" "прилагается" до ОС, а не "прикладывается" для розв'язання задачі (пор. "приложение силы к телу"), думаю, ця плутатина і є причиною існування "додатку" в українській.

Comment: @Miroshko Я в чомусь з вами згоден, слово в даному випадку суперечливе. Додав коментар про це у свою відповідь.

Comment: На мій погляд аплікація та додаток - найгірші варінти

Answer (score 13):

В цьому словосполученні **desktop** вживається як [метафора](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_metaphor) (до інтерфейсу), і вперше її почали використовувати трактуючи монітор комп'ютера як стільницю з об'єктами. Тому переклад "настільний застосунок" є цілком логічним. Але враховуючи, що на дворі вже давно не 80-ті, “desktop application” також можна перекладати як "програма/застосунок для комп'ютера".

Comment: "desktop application" і надалі вказує на тип програм що запускаються на "desktop". на відміну від "web application", "mobile application". Переклад "для компютера" є узагальненням.

Comment: Термін «desktop computer» ще відрізняє «великі» комп'ютери від мобільних/планшетів/тощо. Ваш варіант не відтворює цієї різниці.

Comment: Зазвичай серед українців слово комп'ютер прямо асоціюється, з як Ви написали, "великими комп'ютерами", і чуючи це слово, точно ніхто не подумає про "мобільний комп'ютер" чи "планшетний комп'ютер" чи "супер комп'ютер".

Comment: Погляньте, наприклад, як трактує свій застосунок для desktop компанія скайп https://www.skype.com/uk/download-skype/skype-for-computer/ чи англійською https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/ . Не бачу нічого поганого в узагальнені цього терміну.

Comment: Згоден. ПК в нас — це десктоп чи лаптоп, і з переносними пристроями їх не плутають. Тому «настільний застосунок» або «застосунок для ПК», у разі протиставлення до «веб-, мобільних, серверних» та інших програм, які не можна запускати локально на «ПК» без допоміжних засобів чи які не є користувацькими. Щодо ‘mobile application’, то їх взагалі у нас вже звикли називати «додатками», і це навряд чи зміниться.

Comment: Жодного разу не стикався з використанням слова "застосунок"

Answer (score 9):

Хоча я сам досі не знайшов прийнятного рішення, мені особисто не подобається "стільниковий застосунок" і його похідні. Наскільки я розумію, **application** в даному контексті - це скорочення від **application program**. Abby Lingvo перекладає "application program" як **прикладна програма**. Я зазвичай використовую термін **програма**, а не застосунок - звучить більш звично і зрозуміло.

Щодо поєднання із терміном **desktop**. Не думаю, що варто буквально прив'язуватися до перекладу "настільний",  "не портативний" комп'ютер (*адже це є дуже суперечливим моментом, оскільки сучасні ноутбуки та планшети  можуть запускати такі ж програми)*. Тому, мабуть, правильніше було б перекласти **програма для стільникового комп'ютера** (якщо вам треба акцентувати на цьому увагу), або просто **комп'ютерна програма**. 
Тут вже зазначали, що термін "комп'ютерна програма" є дуже загальний. Однак, якщо брати до уваги останні тенденції, то все частіше можна зустріти випадки запуску одних і тих же програм як на мобільних так і на "десктопних" пристроях.

Comment: `програма для стільникового комп'ютера` за визначенням схоже на програму яка виконується на комп'ютері у мережі стільникового зв'язку. `якщо вам треба акцентувати на цьому увагу` - так, саме це мені і потрібно (я хочу зазначити в резюме, що я маю досвід розробки саме desktop application).

Comment: Програма скоріше підходить в контексті "програма дій" або "програма передач". Компьютерну програму випущену для використання усталено називають "доданок".

Answer (score 3):

### Комп'ютерна програма

Програмне забезпечення ([software applications](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_software) за призначенням щодо устаткування поділяють на два типи: desktop app і mobile app.

Desktop application - це будь-яке ПЗ що може бути встановлене на персональний комп'ютер (windows, macbook).

Mobile application - це мобільні додатки, які можна встановити на телефони з операційними системами android або iOS.

Comment: Цікава відповідь, але я б посперичався. Наприклад ядро ОС Linux може бути встановлено (і встановлюється) і на ПК і на телефони (і на машини і годиники і т.д.). Ба більше, навіть ціла ОС, а не хіба її ядро може бути встановлено і на ПК і на мобільний пристрій (планшет) наприклад Windows або Ubuntu.

Comment: @Gluttton Дякую що зауважили, та не бачу приводу до суперечки. Адже ,історично, Desktop - ПК (персональний комп‘ютер або ще настільний комп‘ютер), що складається з монітору, клавіатури і самого топа. Похідним від нього є ноутбук.

Answer (score 2):

Я вживаю "*Стільничний застосунок*". Від слів "*стільниця*" (desktop) та "*застосунок*" (application).

Водночас, ймовірно це питання варто було б розділити на два: як перекласти *desktop* та як перекласти *application*, адже кожне з них є окремою темою для дискусії.

Comment: ці слова вже давно мають усталені переклади - стільниця та застосунок

Comment: В розмові для мене "програма" є переклад "application" в контексті програмного забезпечення. Це не є точни перекладом слова application але значення передає вірно.

Comment: Так, слово "програма" я теж вживаю в значенні "application". Семантичні відмінності не дуже помітні.

Comment: -1: те, як вживаєте ви, не є достатнім аргументом для хорошої відповіді. Спробуйте додати більш поважні джерела для обґрунтування.

Answer (score 1):

Враховуючи те, що у нас в наявності є декілька середовищ, як то

- комп'ютер
- планшет
- мобільний телефон

Варто прив'язуватись до середовища, а не англійської мови.
Тому *комп'ютерна програма*, або *комп'ютерний застосунок*(ріже вухо) мабуть буде коректним варіантом. Комп'ютер вже давно має чітке значення desktop computer.

Answer (score 0):

Цей термін часто називають *Комп'ютерний застосунок* або ж *аплікація*. Для мобільного відповідно *мобільна аплікація*, але це неточний переклад, бо "аплікація" в українській має зовсім інше значення.

Згідно словників можна [використовувати](http://uk.dictionarist.com/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0/application) *стільниковий застосунок* або *[десктопний застосунок](https://uk.glosbe.com/uk/en/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%96-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA)*.

Comment: Як на мене, аплікація - дуже невдала калька з англійської. По-перше, слово "аплікація" в українській мові має зовсім інше усталене значення (аплікація на папері). По-друге, "мобільна аплікація" для українофона видається цілком незрозумілим словосполученням. З таким же успіхом можна просто вжити оригінальне desktop application.

Answer (score -1):

На мою думку, ані "додаток", ні "застосунок" не прижився в щоденній українській мові.

Що ж, можливо, слід змиритися з запровадженням нового змісту в українській мові для слова "аплікація"

Зрештою, у польській чи болгарській мові вживають саме слово "аплікація" для перекладу англійського терміну desktop або mobile application

Comment: Безвідносно до самої висловленої думки, але Вас скоро замінусують за те, що Ви не наводите джерела. Ви можете навести приклад якоїсь програми, інструкції користувача, книги, часопису або будь-чого, де «desktop application» або «mobile application» було б перекладено як «аплікація»?

Answer (score -2):

Не знайшов для себе причин "дослівного перекладу", - ситуації коли викинуте слово "настільний" категорично щось змінює. То пропоную вживати просто "застосунок". Але коли необхідно виокремити як "стаціонарне робоче місце", то щоб не плутати "настільний застосунок" з якимось пристосуванням можно вживати: "застосунок для персонального комп'ютера", "програмне забезпечення для настільного комп'ютера" та ще декілка варіацій.

Отже сталого значення "desktop application" в українській мові немає. Даже більше скажу сталого значення "desktop application" в англійській мові немає: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Desktop_application&redirect=no

Comment: не згідний що desktop application не має сталого значення, принаймні для тих хто працює в IT, desktop application є доволі визначеним http://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/41158/desktop-application

Answer (score -3):

Мабуть має право на існування як скорочене від *застосунок для настільного ПК*.

Comment: -1: те, як вживаєте ви, не є достатнім аргументом для хорошої відповіді. Спробуйте додати більш поважні джерела для обґрунтування.

Answer (score -4):

"Настільний доданок" або "персональний доданок"

Comment: -1: те, як вживаєте ви, не є достатнім аргументом для хорошої відповіді. Спробуйте додати більш поважні джерела для обґрунтування.

Comment: Українські джерела, що я переглянув ссилаються на неіснуючі вде рішення і закриті сайти. Там, де вдалося знайти першоджерело ще в 2013 точилася суперечка і апелювали до гугла і мікрософта. Офіціозна спроба нав'язати термін "застосунок" провалилася. Використовується "програма" і "доданок". Саме мобільні доданки суттево закріпили позиції терміну "доданок". Посилатися на сумнівні джерела, коли є досвід массового використання термінів при викладанні в колледжі, позашкільних навчальних закладах і в ІТ сфері розробки не бачу смислу

Comment: Можливо "Додаток" а не "доданок"?
Доданок, це дещо з арифметики.