# Що є більш правильним "застосунок" чи "додаток"?

Tags: переклад, терміни, from-english

Мається на увазі "Mobile Application". Останнім часом, я все більше бачу саме слово "застосунок", проте раніше більше було "додатків". Наприклад, в українському Гугл.Плей використовують "додаток".

Comment: «Правильно» завжди суб’єктивно, хіба ні?))

Comment: Вважається хорошим питанням, коли Ви спочатку намагаєтеся провести якусь спробу дослідження самостійно. Ну, наприклад, згадаєте, де Ви ще бачили варіанти «застосунок»/«додаток» окрім Google Play (можливо, навіть спобуєте пошукати) і наведете ці приклади. Питання типу «ось я намагався, знайшов таке, але до кінця розв'язати не можу» і цінуються більше, і відповідаються легше (швидше знаходять відповідь). Хоч я не кажу, що в даному випадку це обов'язкого, але якби Ви згадали та додали в питання — було б значно краще.

Comment: @Sasha - Ну, «неправильний» за рівнем суб’єктивности мало чим відрізняється від «правильного», в мові правильним є той варіянт, що його затверджено Академією, а комп’ютерні терміни сивочолі академики не ладні вчасно затверджувати, бо тих термінів щодня з’являється все більше, й кінця й краю тому не видно. А тим часом слова борються одне з одним і виживає найсильніше.)) Та я згідний з вами щодо формулювання запитань.

Comment: Microsoft — застосунок.

Comment: Англійсько-українсько-англійський словник наукової мови (фізика та споріднені науки) — застосунок.

Comment: KDE: додаток=plugin (а не application).

Comment: Тут схоже питання про настільний доданок:  http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/17/%d0%af%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%97%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%8e-desktop-application   Доданок і додаток різні слова і терміни.

Comment: В такому разі як будете перекладати "a database application"?

Answer (score 25):

"[Застосунок](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA)" та "[Додаток](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA)" є прямими перекладами слова "[Application](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/application)", що є скороченням для [Application Software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_software).

Вираз "Application Software" описує програмне забезпечення, що використовується для прикладних задач: редагування тексту, відтворення медіа, тощо. Отже, слідуючи за семантикою, його прийнято перекладати як "прикладне програмне забезпечення". Термін "застосунок" є близьким за значенням до останнього, як дещо, що має певне застосування для користувача.

З іншого боку, можемо розглянути семантику терміну "додаток" як програми, що була додана до системи для розширення її можливостей. Але у такому випадку переклад не є змістовно точним - системне програмне забезпечення також може не бути власне частиною операційної системи як такої. Більш того, термін "додаток" може використовуватись як "додатковий елемент програми" - "розширення".

На мою думку, обидва терміни є доволі "незграбними" у використанні. "Застосунок" порушує звучання мови, а "додаток" не точно передає зміст. Особисто я використовую терміни "програма" та "прикладна програма".

Додатково, це питання [розглянуто](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA#.D0.A2.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.BC.D1.96.D0.BD_.D0.B2_.D1.83.D0.BA.D1.80.D0.B0.D1.97.D0.BD.D1.81.D1.8C.D0.BA.D1.96.D0.B9_.D0.BC.D0.BE.D0.B2.D1.96) у українському розділі вікі.

Comment: Не зовсім розумію, як "застосунок" порушує звучання мови?

Comment: Звукова група "зстс" з свистячих приголосних є неприємною для слуху та може бути дещо складною для вимови. Загалом це призводить до порушення милозвучності. Втім, це є моєю особистою думкою. Можливо, питання потребує додаткових досліджень.

Comment: Саме вітсутність милозвучності - основна ознака скалічення нашої мови академічними виданнями совкового і пост совкового періоду. Доданок показав свою живучисть. До речі в мікрософт на сайті вони уникають взагалі терміну application.

Comment: Додаток гарно звучить, але дуже часто вживається в українській мові з іншими значеннями. Без контексту не відразу зрозумієш про що йдеться.

Comment: Згоден, що найкраще звучить "програма", але на захист слова "додаток" скажу, що зараз популярними стали *платформи* (наприклад, Chrome), у яких додаткові програми називаються все ж таки додатками (або розширеннями, англ. extension, plugin). У чомусь це подібно до програм у звичайній операційній системі, тому іноді по аналогії допускається і програми називати додатками. У якийсь момент *платформи* і *операційні системи* стануть одним і тим самим (якщо ще не стали), і тоді програми і додатки буде взагалі не розрізнити.

Comment: Про застосунок можна от точно так само сказати що «неточний» переклад − бо системне пз також має «певне застосування для користувача». Так що це нмсд не аргумент.

Comment: Я б сказав, що застосунок, бо _application_ program — програма, яка має застосування, прикладна. Системні зазвичай не прикладні, а утилітарні. А додаток взагалі дико, бо це вже ближче до attachment, чи на худий кінець, розширення/плагін/віджет — те, що вбудовується в іншу систему, _додаючи_ якісь можливості.

Comment: До речі, з яких це пір додаток став прямим перекладом application? Це вже контекстно-залежний художній переклад. Бо корінь apply — прикладати, застосовувати.

Comment: P.S. Як на мене, нейтральний переклад "прикладна програма" теж непоганий і дуже точний.

Comment: Приведіть приклади вжитку "застосунок".

Comment: Application Software - це ПО, що можна додати на пристрій, яке не входить до базової комплектації.

Answer (score 10):

Суперечка *додаток vs. застосунок* є однією з найпопулярніших серед технічної спільноти і кожен варіант має своїх прихильників та противників.

Терміни *додаток* і *застосунок* є точними перекладами англійського слова *application*, хоча в українській мові обидва варіанти не відображають повністю суть цього терміну. *Застосунок* зустрічається частіше, оскільки *applicable* - *придатний* або *такий, який можна **застосувати***. Натомість, *додаток* є популярним через подвійний переклад терміну з російської, а саме *application - приложение - додаток*.

В деяких регіонах також є популярним варіант *аплікація*, що, звісно, є просто калькою з англійською, і конфліктує з іншим значенням - накладання, пристосовування, приєднання до якоїсь поверхні.

Тому наразі загальновживані як *додаток*, так і *застосунок*.

Comment: А ще «Додаток» популярний тому що легко вимовляється і тому що він є усюди в Ґуґл Плей, а більшість людей як відомо мають андроїд телефони.

Comment: "Аплікація" мабуть не з англійської, а десь з чеської aplikace (хоча туди вона певно з англійської потрапила). У мене основна асоціація із творчими поробками з дитинства, де треба було наклеювати різні вирізки штуки на аркуш паперу.

Answer (score -1):

Я до додатку звик, звідки з'явилося слово застосунок таке враження що це хтось спеціально карьожмть мову... з мого оточення всі кажуть додаток і це не так піде слух гарне українське слово чітко передає сенсч свого значення