# Як перекласти українською "software framework"?

Tags: переклад, терміни, from-english

Останнім часом значного поширення досягли так звані *software frameworks*, а з ними набуло нового значення і слово *framework*. Ресурс "Technopedia" [подає](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/14384/software-framework) таке тлумачення даного поняття:

> конкретна чи концептуальна платформа, де загальний код із загальною
>   функціональністю може бути вибірково визначений або перевизначений
>   розробниками або користувачами.

Після народження *software framework* почав мандрувати нашої планетою і, звісно, захотів познайомитися з іншими мовами. Наприклад, в німецькій мові він [не змінився](http://www.itwissen.info/Framework-framework.html) (ein Framework), поляки [використовують](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) *platforma programistyczna* [або](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework) *szablon*, росіяни або [транслітерують](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django), або  [кажуть](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) *программная платформа*. А як щодо української мови?

Можна зустріти багато варіантів: і [транслітерований](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django) *фреймворк*, і [ближчий](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails) *програмний каркас*, і та ж [знайома](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) *платформа*. Чи існує офіційний переклад даного терміну?

Comment: Не бачу причин, чому не можна запозичити слово «фреймворк». Так чи інакше, і «каркас», і «платформа», і «шаблон» — запозичення, причому, доволі пізні (ймовірно, ХХ ст. чи, щонайдавніше, кінця ХІХ).

Comment: вважаю що фреймворк в першу чергу є "інструментом", тому можна вважати це слово натомість

Answer (score 10):

Я б не вживав слово "платформа", адже platform вже має інше визначення - див. [ця відповідь на StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25028331/1168152).

Платформа - програмне забезпечення і "фізичне" залізо, середовище в якому існує ваша програма, аплікація чи фреймворк. Тут слово "платформа" логічно підходить.

Каркас - непогане слово, але чи приживеться воно? В будь-якому разі, поки воно не прижилось, ви будете в своєрідному мовному "авангарді" і вам прийдеться постійно пояснювати що це за звір такий, або ставити в дужки (фреймворк).

Якщо подивитись на переклади іншими мовами, майже всі вживають framework - іспанська, французька, німецька і т.д. Інколи усюдисущий інгліш непереможний. Gotta pick your linguistic battles. Думаю краще саме **фреймворк**.

Comment: Дякую Вам за відповідь! Будь ласка, почитайте про [наші критерії](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/36), за якими ми оцінюємо хороші відповіді. Ваша відповідь побудована на суб'єктивній думці та власному досвіді, буде чудово, якщо Ви підкріпите її авторитетними джерелами.

Comment: Я б не радив вживати термін `аплікація` в IT-галузі, адже він [означає](http://sum.in.ua/s/aplikacija) виготовлення орнаментів чи яких-небудь художніх зображень нашиванням або наклеюванням на що-небудь різнокольорових клаптиків тканини, паперу. Див. також [цю](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/173/352) відповідь.

Answer (score 5):

- Інфраструктура:

  - І. обробки подій *[event f.]*. І. для показу персоніфікованої інформації *[Content Selection F.]*. І. обробника бізнес-логіки *[business logic handler f.]*. І. UPnP. І. постачальника облікових даних *[Credential Provider F.]*. І. рішень Microsoft SharePoint *[Microsoft SharePoint Solutions F.]*. І. тестування магазину Windows *[Windows Store Testing F.]*. Портативна і. .Net *[portable .Net f.]*. Компоненти і. *[f. components]*. І. зв'язку пристроїв *[Device Association F.]*. *<sub>[MS](//www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=framework&langID=uk-ua)</sub>*.
- Каркас:

  - Розробник к. *[f. developer]*. К. панелі навігації. *<sub>[KDE](//l10n.kde.org/team-infos.php?teamcode=uk)</sub>*.
  - К. драйверів режиму користувача.  *<sub>[MS](//www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=framework&langID=uk-ua)</sub>*.
- Комплекс:

  - Шаблони для різних систем збирання та к. *[templates for different build-systems and f.]*. К. PHPUnit. К. PyUnit. *<sub>[KDE](//l10n.kde.org/team-infos.php?teamcode=uk)</sub>*.
- Концепція:

  - К. безпечного передавання даних *[Safe Harbor F.]*. *<sub>[MS](//www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=framework&langID=uk-ua)</sub>*.
- Набір бібліотек:

  - Н. мультимедійних б. *[multimedia f.]*. *<sub>[KDE](//l10n.kde.org/team-infos.php?teamcode=uk)</sub>*.
- Оболонка:

  - О. для роботи з пристроями Solid. О. отримання нових даних. О. QGraphicsView. О. керування особистою інформацією Akonadi. *<sub>[KDE](//l10n.kde.org/team-infos.php?teamcode=uk)</sub>*.
- Платформа:

  - Портування до п. <назва>. Портування на п. <назва>. Додаток *[plugin]* до п. <назва>. *<sub>[KDE](//l10n.kde.org/team-infos.php?teamcode=uk)</sub>*.
  - П. Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. *<sub>[MS](//www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=framework&langID=uk-ua)</sub>*.
- Середовище:

  - С. налаштування серверів *[backend configuration f.]*. *<sub>[KDE](//l10n.kde.org/team-infos.php?teamcode=uk)</sub>*.
  - С. підключення *[connector f.]*. С. діагностики мережі *[Network Diagnostics F.]*. С. текстових служб *[Text Services F.]*. С. майстра інсталяції *[Setup Wizard F.]*. С. шлюзу *[gate f.]*. С. сценарію *[scenario f.]*. С. оцінювання *[evaluation f.]*. С. для виконання автоматизованих перетворень документів *[f. for performing automated document conversions]*. *<sub>[MS](//www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=framework&langID=uk-ua)</sub>*.
- Система:

  - C. визначення розташування GeoClue *[GeoClue Location F.]*. С. WebAccounts. *<sub>[KDE](//l10n.kde.org/team-infos.php?teamcode=uk)</sub>*.
  - С. обслуговування клієнтів *[Customer Care F.]*. С. групової політики.  *<sub>[MS](//www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=framework&langID=uk-ua)</sub>*.
- Структура:

  - С. малювання кривих *[The Curve F.]*. *<sub>[KDE](//l10n.kde.org/team-infos.php?teamcode=uk)</sub>*.
  - С. політики фільтрації відправників *[sender policy f.]*. С. майстра служби Microsoft PerformancePoint *[Microsoft PerformancePoint Wizard F.]*. С. веб-служб Windows *[Windows Web Services f.]*. *<sub>[MS](//www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=framework&langID=uk-ua)</sub>*.

Comment: Зустрічала «програмне середовище». Так можна?

Comment: @ata_zh, ну, «програмне середовище» **не є точним відбиттям** змісту поняття «framework» («програмне середовище», здається, є дослівним перекладом для «[software environment](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_environment)» (ще [посилання](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/S/software_environment.html))). Але **так іноді кажуть** — зокрема тому, що єдиного, усталеного і точного перекладу для «framework» наразі немає. Як бачите, KDE і Microsoft іноді перекладають «framework» навіть як просто «середовище».

Answer (score 4):

В контексті розробки програмного забезпечення «framework», як правило, є гіпонімом до «library» (або «set of libraries»). Тобто поняття «фреймворк» [не завжди](http://www.programcreek.com/2011/09/what-is-the-difference-between-a-java-library-and-a-framework/) є повним синонімом до поняття «бібліотека» («набір бібліотек»), тим не менш найчастіше це або певний підтип бібліотеки (набору бібліотек), або все таки [повний синонім](//stackoverflow.com/a/148852/1421194).

Оскільки переклад поняття «library» як «бібліотека» вже встоявся (хоч він і не є найточнішим), я пропоную в контексті розробки програмного забезпечення перекладати «framework»: або як «**бібліотека**» (чи «**набір бібліотек**»), або, коли фреймворк справді відрізняється, якось уточнювати: «**каркасна бібліотека**», «**набір каркасних** / **каркасний набір бібліотек**».

Аби не множити [buzzword](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buzzword)'и і в українській мові. Це моя особиста думка.

Comment: Фреймворк != бібліотека

Comment: @DenisKurochkin, але це частковий випадок, хіба ні?

Comment: ні, фреймворк — це не завжди бібліотека чи набір бібліотек, це також можуть бути API, утиліти тощо. Навіть якщо фреймворк виглядає як одна бібліотека, правильно називати цю бібліотеку фреймворком, а називати фреймворк бібліотекою – ні.