# Застосунок - приспособление чи приложение?

Tags: переклад, значення-слів

Недавно почула слово "застосунок". Спочатку подумала, що російською його можна перекласти як "приспособление". Почала шукати в мережі і знайшла визначення:

> Застосу́нок, застосо́вна програ́ма або прикладна́ програ́ма (англ. application, application software, app) — користувацька комп'ютерна програма, що дає змогу вирішувати конкретні прикладні задачі користувача.

Тобто це якась певна комп'ютерна програма, російською "приложение"?

Comment: _Застосунок_ (від _застосування_) теоретично могло б позначати багато речей. Але на практиці справді найчастіше позначає прикладну програму, тобто російською _приложение_. У тому ж значенні іноді використовують слова _додаток_, _аплікація_ і, власне, _[прикладна] програма_.

Comment: Див. також [«Як правильно буде українською „desktop application“?»](/q/17) і [«Що є більш правильним „застосунок“ чи „додаток“?»](/q/61).

Comment: Переклад на московську, гадају, льіпше шукати на Russian Exchange. Тут про украјиньську, а не московську.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Що є більш правильним "застосунок" чи "додаток"?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/61/%d0%a9%d0%be-%d1%94-%d0%b1%d1%96%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%81%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%87%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba)

Comment: @follower, з одного боку, так. А з іншого, якщо автор прагне **зрозуміти**, що саме означає слово _застосунок_ (а переклад на російську — це лише як один із шляхів для неї точніше зрозуміти значення, бо російською вона, можливо, в певних сферах володіє краще, ніж українською) — то це саме сюди. Бо там, на Russian, імовірно скажуть: «ми не можемо навести російський еквівалент, допоки Ви не поясните, що саме означає _застосунок_» — а це, можливо, саме і є те, чого не знає та прагне дізнатися автор.

Comment: @Sasha ви вказали на означенньа слова, а не переклад. Коли означенньа — без питань, ја не проти, але тут ж кінцевоју метоју је переклад. Буде вельми дивно на тому ж English просити переклад на украјиньську јакогось анґліјського слова.

Answer (score 2):

У [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA) пише:

> ***Раніше***, в українській комп'ютерній термінології слово ***«застосунок» не зустрічалося***, а словосполучення ***«application»***, «application program» традиційно перекладалося як «прикладна програма», або ж використовувалось слово ***«додаток»***, яке є ***помилковим перекладом російського «приложение»***. Слід зауважити, що російський термін **«приложение»** у російській мові має **два значення — «додаток» або ж «застосування для вирішення практичної задачі», «прикладання на практиці».** З цієї причини *переклад українською російського «приложение» як «додаток» є некоректним, оскільки не відображає початкової суті оригінального терміна (прикладання до вирішення практичної задачі), натомість є прямим перекладом омоніму з іншим значенням і в підсумку неправильно означає нібито додатковість, другорядність програмного забезпечення*.

Також знайшла й обговорення у [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA_%E2%86%92_%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F) статей "Застосунок - Застосування", у підсумку якого висуваються різні пропозиції, зокрема й розмежувати  **застосунок і застосОвання**.

Якщо ж звернутися у [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/zastosunok), слова "застосунок" там не знайдемо, однак знайдемо статті [застосування](http://sum.in.ua/s/zastosuvannja) та ["застосувати"](http://sum.in.ua/s/zastosovuvaty):

> **ЗАСТОСУВА́ННЯ**, я, сер. ***Дія за значенням застосувати***.
>
> **ЗАСТОСО́ВУВАТИ**, ую, уєш, недок., ЗАСТОСУВА́ТИ, ую, уєш, док., перех.
>
> 1. Використовувати що-небудь, запроваджувати в ужиток.
> 2. Пристосовувати до чого-небудь.

Якщо ж у новіший [СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=206593&page=1054), то там вже є таке:

> **ЗАСТОСУ́НОК**, нку, ч., інформ. Те саме, що **застосува́ння 2**.

Звідси:

> **ЗАСТОСУВА́ННЯ**, я, с. **2.** інформ.
>
> ***Виконуваний модуль для певної операційної системи***.
>
> Розроблення моделей об'єктного подання знань про застосування (прикладну систему) є традиційним завданням теорії програмування (з наук. літ.)

Отже, як на мене, у поданому випадку відбулося змішування значень, звідки  "застосунок" має 2 значення:

1. додаток
2. утворений іменник від слова "застосування", що означає дію за значенням.

Answer (score 0):

[Російсько-український словник з інженерних технологій 2013р. (Марія Ганіткевич, Богдан Кінаш)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)

> Приложе́ние
>
> 1. приклада́ння, додава́ння; прикла́дення, додання́; дода́ток,-тку
> 2. застосува́ння; застосо́вування

[Російсько-український народний сучасний словник 2009–](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)

> Приложение –
>
> 1) (несов.) прикладання, застосовування, докладування, долучування,
>   додавання, притулювання; (сов.) прикладення, застосування, докладання,
>   долучення, додання, притулення, (печати) прикладення, притиснення,
>   відтиснення;
>
> 2) (добавление) ***додаток***, (редко) прилога, (программа) застосовна
>   (прикладна) програма, ***застосунок***;
>
> 3) (грам.) прикладка

На сайті [OnlineCorrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0/) вказано

> Замініть іменник додаток, якщо мовиться про прикладну програму
>   (англійською application), на стилістично кращий варіант: програма,
>   застосунок (термін з Microsoft Windows Vista i Windows 7, згодом від
>   нього відмовилися на користь терміна програма).

[Мова - ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/inshe/mobilnuj-dodatok-chu-zastosunok)

[image]
***Отже, застосунок=приложение.***